# Function inside a package is slower than outside the package

Tags: rcpp, r-package

I use Rcpp and RcppArmadillo and i have a "strange" problem. Lets say that i have function f1(). I include this function inside my package and run the command "R CMD INSTALL". After it's done i run a benchmark and i realise that f1 is slower about 100 microseconds inside the package than outside. So if a function wants 100ms to finish, in the package wants about 200+ms.

Code:

functions.cpp

```
vec f1(vec x){
    vec F( x.size() );
    for( int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i ){
         // do something 
    }
    return F;
}
```

exportfunctions.cpp

```
vec f1(vec x);
RcppExport SEXP MyPackage_f1(SEXP xSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    RObject  __result;
    RNGScope __rngScope;
    traits::input_parameter< vec >::type      x(xSEXP);
    __result = wrap(f1(x));
   return __result;
END_RCPP
}
```

exportfunctions.R

```
f1<- function(x) {
    .Call( ' MyPackage_f1 ' , PACKAGE = ' MyPackage ', x )
}
```

An example of how my code is been written.
I believe the problem is that a function.R calls a function.cpp wich calls the final function. But why is this happening inside the package and not in sourceCpp. I can't understand the difference.

Answer (score 5):

Briefly:

- 100ms is a non-issue. You are coming from R which is an interpreted environment
- Calling a function involves several steps. Finding a function in a package involves some more.
- See the documentation for `.Call()` to see how to minimize lookup.
- See the documentation for `NAMESPACE` to set identifiers there too.

The latter two points should help close the gap between *calling an ad-hoc function in the environment* (which is cheaper) verses calling a function from the *properly created infrastructure for doing so* a.k.a. a package.

Comment: I agree than is not an issue but when I sourceCp p the function it needs about 22ms and the same R's function need about 100ms for a vector of 1000 cells. Guess what happened when I call the same function from inside the package, it's slower than R's. Thats why I wonder what is happening behind. I will read the documentation about .call. thanks for the answer!

Comment: You just restated your question again. _These are different code paths to get to your function_ and that is why the timing is different.  _C'est la vie._  By the way I wasn't the one downvoting your question.

Comment: Ok then thanks for your answer and your help. I will read the documentations. Thanks for the inform about downvoting.